# SQL Count Available Rooms

Tags: asp.net

I am a newbie using asp.net I have a problem on what I am going to use. The problem is that i should count the number of available rooms in a hotel using SQL I use count but it's not working is there any  way to use?

Comment: Try @Joel Caihoorn answer..there is no problem in you query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's not the direct answer to your question, but it'd be much simpler if you just used `ExecuteScalar` to get your count value, since you only have one row/value being returned:

```
int count = (int) cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
availableRMS.Text = count;
```

Since Count will always return a number with your query in SQL Server (zero if no rows), then you don't need all the extra checks required for using the reader.

Answer (score 3):

```
availableRMS.Text = rdr.Item(0)
```

First first column in the table is at the 0 index, not the 1 index